# wxWidgets 3.1.0 project error on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, wxwidgets

i am a newbie here and i need help in compiling my wxwidgets project to work with codeblocks.

i downloaded wxwidgets windows intaller 'wxMSW-3.1.0-Setup.exe' from http://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/

i run the program to install, then i read about making environmental variable at system properties>>advanced system settings>>environment variables. thus i made it by setting variable name as "path" and variable value as "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin".

also read about making builds for wxwidget in cmd prompt, so launch cmd and input such procedures below (some which took a long time).

1. mingw32-make -v
2. cd C:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\build\msw
3. mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc clean
4. mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=debug SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1
5. mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1

after all that i went on to make a wxwidgets project.
i got two errors when making wxwidgets project  "a matching debug configuration cannot be found in the wxwidgets directory you specified" and "a matching release configuration cannot be found in the wxwidgets directory you specified"

but then i skip and went on to project, after build and run i got these errors below.

Build log for debug:

-------------- Build: Debug in testwx (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\gcc_lib -o bin\Debug\testwx.exe  obj\Debug\testwxApp.o obj\Debug\testwxMain.o obj\Debug\resource.res -mthreads  -lwxmsw30u -lwxpng -lwxjpeg -lwxtiff -lwxzlib -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomctl32 -lwsock32 -lodbc32 -mwindows
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxmsw30u
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 5 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 5 second(s))

Build log for release:

-------------- Build: Release in testwx (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

windres.exe -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\include -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\gcc_lib\mswu  -J rc -O coff -i C:\Users\AJIKAH~1\DOCUME~1\Programs\WXWIDG~1\testwx\resource.rc -o obj\Release\resource.res
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wall -O2 -std=c++11 -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\include -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\gcc_lib\mswu -c "C:\Users\A JIKAH\Documents\Programs\wxWidgets\testwx\testwxApp.cpp" -o obj\Release\testwxApp.o
mingw32-g++.exe -pipe -mthreads -D__GNUWIN32__ -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_UNICODE -Wall -O2 -std=c++11 -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\include -IC:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\gcc_lib\mswu -c "C:\Users\A JIKAH\Documents\Programs\wxWidgets\testwx\testwxMain.cpp" -o obj\Release\testwxMain.o
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\wxWidgets-3.1.0\lib\gcc_lib -o bin\Release\testwx.exe  obj\Release\testwxApp.o obj\Release\testwxMain.o obj\Release\resource.res -s -mthreads  -lwxmsw30u -lwxpng -lwxjpeg -lwxtiff -lwxzlib -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomctl32 -lwsock32 -lodbc32 -mwindows
C:/Program Files (x86)/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxmsw30u
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 33 second(s))
2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 33 second(s))

now i update code::blocks 16.01 to code::blocks 17.01.

can someone pls help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you downloaded "wxMSW-3.1.0-Setup.exe".  But this part "...cannot find -lwxmsw30u..." means you're trying to link with libraries from wxWidgets 3.0.

To make sure your project is trying to link with the correct version of wxWidgets, on the second page of the codeblocks wizard (the one that says "Please select the wxWidgets version you want to use"), be sure to select the "wxWidgets 3.1.x" option.

Another common cause of the "matching configuration cannot be found" problem is not selecting the right options on the 8th page of the wizard (the one that says "Please select various configuration options").  Since you said you build the library with the options " SHARED=0 MONOLITHIC=1 UNICODE=1", be sure to check "wxWidgets is built as a monolithic library" and "Enable unicode" and be sure "Use wxWidgets DLL" is unchecked.

Comment: Thanks very much! this has solved my problem but  am still having issue after i build and run wxWidgets project. Error Message "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error".

Comment: I have no clue what could cause that problem.  MinGW applications do use a C runtime (specifically MSVCRT.DLL), but they do not use any Microsoft C++ runtime libraries.  (In fact it would be almost impossible for a MinGW application to use them.)  Are you maybe trying to mix MinGW and Visual C++?

Comment: Thanks for helping, but i have just change my mind on wxwidgets to Qt.

Answer (score 0):

@MrSudden,

Is there any reason why you built the library as MONOLITHIC?

This configuration, also supported, is not recommended and can cause problems in the long run.
It is also does not have a big testing from the core wx team, and so have a big chances of breakage.

There is no gain of building "monolithic" library vs. "multilib" one.

Thank you.

Comment: Nice Observation! Do you recommend i change to Multilib, and if so what will be the best method with regards to my current state?

Comment: @MrSudden, the best would be to recompile the library without the MONOLITHIC option and in C::B when you create the project make sure not to use that option (don't use C::B, so just check the New Pagodi reply). In terms of you run-time issue - again, as New Pagodi said, make sure there is no mix with the compiler. In addition, make sure you can successfully compile and run 'minimal' sample provided with the library.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but i have just change my mind on wxwidgets to Qt.